# Dual Boot Menu Missing - Can't open Luna

Tags: boot, elementary

I'm certain that I correctly installed Elementary Luna OS alongside Vista, but my computer doesn't seem to recognize it.

There is no dual boot menu, and when I press F12 or F8 during start up, I can't find any option for Luna.

The advanced system properties in the Vista control panel doesn't show an option for Luna either.

When I tried Snyper's suggestion, everything seemed to go fine, but I still can't open Luna:

> /dev/sda2 on /media/ACER type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
>
> /dev/sda3 on /media/DATA type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
>
> **/dev/sdb5 on /media/06f44361-143e-4960-9e07-d04b5e9f4646 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)**
>
> /dev/sdb1 on /media/64ECE79BECE76630 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
>
> elementary@elementary:~$ sudo mount --bind /dev /media/06f44361-143e-4960-9e07-d04b5e9f4646/dev
>
> elementary@elementary:~$ sudo mount --bind /sys /media/06f44361-143e-4960-9e07-d04b5e9f4646/sys
>
> elementary@elementary:~$ sudo mount --bind /proc /media/06f44361-143e-4960-9e07-d04b5e9f4646/proc
>
> elementary@elementary:~$ sudo chroot /media/06f44361-143e-4960-9e07-d04b5e9f4646
>
> root@elementary:/# grub-install /dev/sdb
>
> Installation finished. No error reported.
>
> root@elementary:/# update-grub
>
> Generating grub.cfg ...
>
> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-51-generic-pae
>
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-51-generic-pae
>
> done
>
> root@elementary:/# exit
>
> exit

Comment: Are the two installations on separate drives?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  I just "installed alongside" vista, which led me to a slider to adjust space.     

Actually, I don't think so:  Luna ate a lot of my space on C (where vista is).

Comment: Do you still have the Elementary live media?

Comment: Yes. You mean the DVD/CD/USB, right?

Comment: Yes. It's possible that grub (the Luna boot menu) didn't install correctly. If that's the case, we can chroot into the Luna installation from the DVD and install grub properly from there. I'll have an answer typed shortly.

Comment: Will that kill more of my free space?

Comment: Not much, I believe. Maybe several kilobytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if GRUB was installed incorrectly. We can chroot into the Luna partition and re-install GRUB rather easily.

Boot into the Luna DVD. When you have done so, open the file manager and, in the list on the left, click on the partition that Luna is installed on. This will mount your partition.

Next, open a terminal and type `mount`. The line showing your Luna partition should be near the bottom, and will look something like this:

```
/dev/sda1 on /media/name type ext4 (rw,nodev)
```

In my example the partition was `/dev/sda1` and the mountpoint was `/media/name`. The actual values, especially for `/media/name`, will possibly be different.

Now, in the terminal, type

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /media/name/dev
sudo mount --bind /sys /media/name/sys
sudo mount --bind /proc /media/name/proc
```

where `/media/name` is the value we found previously.

This will mount the needed directories from your Luna installation so that we can chroot into it.

In the terminal again, type `chroot /media/name`.
You should now be seeing a root shell prompt (which should end in `#`).

If you have only one hard drive, type

`grub-install /dev/sda` (where /dev/sda is the partition name that `mount` showed us, but **do not** use the number at the end)
And then:

```
update-grub
```

This will reinstall GRUB, and update it so that it recognizes Vista.
If you have multiple drives, use the value that the `mount` command we typed earlier gave us, but without the number at the end.

Now we're finished. In the terminal, type `exit`, which will make you leave the chroot. You may now restart, and hopefully GRUB will be displayed when next you boot.

Comment: So that still didn't work.   Was I supposed to do "grub-install /dev/sdb"  or "grub-install /dev/sub update-grub"?   The latter gave me an error.

Comment: grub-install /dev/sdb and then just update-grub, without the partition name after it.

Comment: There was a formatting error in the answer--I apologize for that. I've changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.   Do you think I'd have better luck trying to uninstall and start over? I posted my failed terminal log above.

Comment: And it still doesn't show when you reboot? The only thing I can think of would be that Luna was installed on a different hard drive and that your motherboard is booting into the Vista one by default, but from what you've said that can't be the case.
I guess you could try a re-install, and see if that works.
I'm really sorry that I couldn't help you further.